# Writing an app using Spring MVC, angular js and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How should a secure application be written using Spring MVC, angular js and javascript ?

Let's say I am getting an object Participant from the server in the angular UI.

```
Participant {
    id
    name
    address
    status - this status is determined on the server by some logic, whether this participant is active or not
    }
```

On my UI, the user the can change address and then submit changes.

Since the whole object is on the front end, the user can go in to javascript and change the value for status easily.

On the server, I save the whole object as it is.

What I want to know is that, how does a secure app control this ? What's the norm ? Do I just send properties to the UI that the user is allowed to modify ? Or is there any other way of accomplishing this kind of security ?

Comment: There is no way you can secure the code that is run in the browser. It's public code and can be seen, hacked and modified at will. All security must be handled by the server.

Comment: Right, so would you just send id, name and address to the client and not send status ? i.e. define a different object class to send/rcv to/frm client ? Or do you send the same object and then on submit, on the server, don't update value of 'status' ?

Comment: I don't really know, because I don't know how important or secret "status" is to you. Just keep in mind that the code run in the browser cannot be 100% secured. It can be checked (form validation), but not secured or hidden. So yeah you have no choice, everything you send client-side can be modified by the user. Start from here and try to figure out your architecture.

Comment: K. Thanks for your help.